# How to handle lazy login?

Tags: ios, authentication, modal-dialog

I don't want my app to require login as soon as it launches.  Instead, I'd like to prompt the user to login on a 'per need' basis.  So for example if the user interacts with a part of the app that requires him to be logged in, only then will the login prompt appear.

I have a couple of questions:

1) Has anyone ever done this kind of 'lazy' login before, and if so what has your experience been?  Is it awkward to manage?  Is it a confusing experience to the user?

2) What's the best way to implement this?

I have a LoginViewController which prompts for user login.  I'd like to display this view controller modally on top of whichever view controller's view is visible at the time.

I'd also like for the various other view controllers to know nothing about the LoginViewController to minimize coupling.

Ideally I'd have some LoginManager singleton which would manage anything to do with logging in.

Then for example if some random view controller MyCoolViewController needs user authentication for a certain feature, like a button being pressed, it could call:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    // If the user isn't logged in, show the login modal view on top of this VC
    if (![[LoginManager sharedManager] requireLoginWithViewController:self]) {
        return;
    }

    // Code that is protected by login
}
```

But then I need a way to know whether login was successful.  This can be solved by delegation or callbacks, but implies the view controllers each know something about the LoginController which I'd like to avoid.

Another approach is to create a ProtectedViewController subclass of UIViewController which all my view controllers would subclass and would provide functionality for accessing protected functionality, and presenting the login controller when needed.

What do you think of these approaches?  Is there anything else that makes more sense?  I'd love to hear your experience regarding 'lazy' login.

Comment: This appears to be a valid implementation. Just make sure that there's nothing that you wouldn't want an identity theft seeing :)

Comment: Do you need to let them register also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up choosing an implementation that hides login details from consumers of the network manager while still remaining agnostic to the login implementation details.

I achieved this with 3 classes:

- NetworkManager (singleton interface to the web service)
- LoginManager (singleton login coordinator)
- LoginViewController (vc to show the login interface such as the login button)

The NetworkManager has a loginDelegate which is responsible for handling app-specific login UI.  In this case, the LoginManager singleton is this loginDelegate.

The general flow is:

1. The app requests data from the server via the NetworkManager
2. If the request authentication fails, the NetworkManager tells its loginDelegate that it should now handle some kind of login flow.
3. The LoginManager then presents a LoginViewController modally on the window's rootViewController.
4. When the login button is pressed, the LoginViewController tells the LoginManager that it wants to login.
5. The LoginManager in turn uses the NetworkManager to perform the actual server login.
6. When login completes the LoginManager is notified via a callback block.  If successful, the LoginViewController is dismissed.

There's a bit of back and forth between the LoginManager and the LoginViewController but this allows the NetworkManager to be consumed without needing knowledge about the login flow.  Additionally the NetworkManager can be reused in another app because it knows nothing about app-specific login visuals (hence the need for the delegate).

Delegation isn't usually used with singletons, but I think it's ok in this case because there should only ever be one login delegate (in theory there should be one flow for logging in in the app).

This is the first approach and will probably be refined with time.  Perhaps using notifications to notify the rest of the app that the user logged in could be a good next step.

Answer (score 0):

I had implement this method of lazy logging on the following way (without problems):

1. Created a settings view with logout, login (username/password), it can be a general login page, or a UIWebView.
2. The app sent the data to the server for authentication (in JSON message).
3. Succes login: I stored the login data in the keychain (using singleton pattern, see [this Apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html) or [this tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html))
4. if the user want to use a sensitive part of the app, I requested the password of the stored username, and the was able to logout and login with different account. The app compared the typed password with the stored one (*offline mode*) or send it to the server(online connection). But it can be implemented on different ways depending the requirements.

And the user like it!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your question already holds most of the answers. That said, you should go for the singleton login manager. I'd implement login something like this:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    // If the user isn't logged in, show the login modal view on top of this VC
    if ([[LoginManager sharedManager] requiresLogin]) {

        [[LoginManager sharedManager] loginWithViewController:self completion:^{
            [self buttonPressed:sender];
        }];

        return;
    }

    // Code that is protected by login
}
```

In this way, your login management is still anonymous, and asynchronously your login manager can resume the operation where it left off for the user to login.

Comment: Makes sense, but I decided to move away from this kind of approach because I didn't want a bunch of different parts of the app to have to individually handle the login checks and flow.